# Allow a second user to access a folder

Tags: centos, file-permissions

**Use case:**

I've got two users `nginx` and `nodejs` and I want to run a nginx server which serves static files, which have been created by the nodejs user (from `git pull`).

**The problem:**

I noticed that I would get permissions denied on open file in the nginx log when I first tried. What I did is adding the `nginx` user to the `nodejs` group (which is also the nodejs user's group). I confirmed that the nginx user is in this group by running `groups` (as nginx user).

However that still didn't work. So I logged in as `nginx` user and tried to access the folder which contains the assets it is supposed to serve:

```
[nginx@m5465 home]$ cd nodejs
bash: cd: nodejs: Permission denied
```

Folder permissions:

[image]

**The question:**

How can I give the nginx user read permissions for the desired folder and it's files (`/home/nodejs/projectname/wwwroot/`) / What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did I get -1 for my question? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [nginx@m5465 home]$ cd nodejs
>   bash: cd: nodejs: Permission denied

From your image the permissions on the nodejs directory are `rwxr------`. To be able to traverse a directory structure, a process needs to have `x` (traverse) [permission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) at some level. Your group permissions are too restrictive. You need to add `x` to the directory at the group level e.g.

```
chmod g+x nodejs.
```

You will need to do this for each directory that nginx needs to be able to traverse.

As you are on a CentOS system you may also be having issues with SELinux. You can confirm this by looking in /var/log/audut/audit.log looking for denied messages. To confirm if SELinux is causing an issue you can temporarily put it it permissive mode.

```
setenforce 0
```

If your actions now work then this is proved and you will need to make changes as appropriate. This could be as simple as enabling the `httpd_enable_homedirs` (but that may give away more than you want) or something more complex but less open.

Comment: The `chmod g+x nodejs` did the trick. Thanks a lot!